# JavaScript make object a global window object? (no Conflict functionality)

Tags: javascript

I didn't know how to word the question but basically I have an object like this.

```
var framework = {
    view: function(){

    },
    model: function(){

    }
}
```

That would obviously be used like this `new framework.view()` or similar.

How would i make it so that these are just available as `view` and `model`. besides adding a chunk of code at the bottom like this

```
var view = framework.view;
var model = framework.model;
```

Understand this is similar functionality the createjs offers and jQuery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out....

adding this code above the framework declaration

```
var framework = window;
```

and then adding properties rather than overwriting them like so

```
framework.view = function(){

}
```

this can now be accessed by either `framework.view` or `view`

Comment: putting variables on the global scope is considered a bad practice, just so you'd know. I might cause conflicts with other code, because it is not isolated. what you practically did it just this: `var view = function(){...`. but you did it with a spaghetti code.

Comment: I understand that, but if i create framework within one object it can be used easily, and if no conflicts would appear (depending on the project) I would push it into the window, so i don't have to type framework every time i reference something!